# Report and Alert Configuration- Email send but cant Receive

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, apache-superset

I create a report on latest version of apache superset on ubuntu 20.04 and add report alert with 1 minute interval. log file show me email send but I cannot receive email. can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have to edit your `superset_config.py` file to include the credentials of your SMTP server.
Refer to the documentation below on how to go about it.

https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/alerts-reports/